GTM249 Fourier Analysis - Problem 7.1.8
Here's the problem: Let $k>0$. If $1\leq p<\infty$ and $w\in A_p$, show that
$$[\min(w,k)]_{A_p}\leq c_p[w]_{A_p}$$
where $c_p=1$ if $1<p\leq 2$ and $c_p =2^{p−1}$ if $2<p<\infty$.
I first follow the hint to prove the following two inequalities:
$$\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q\min(w,k)^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx\leq \frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx+k^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q\min(w,k)dx\leq \min(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qwdx,k)$$
where $Q$ is an arbitrary cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we assume that $1<p\leq 2$, then $(a+b)^{p-1}\leq a^{p-1}+b^{p-1}$ for all $a,b\geq 0$. We then can deduce that
\begin{align*}
&(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q\min(w,k)dx)(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q\min(w,k)^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx)^{p-1}\\
&\leq \min(k,\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Bwdx)(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx+k^{-\frac{1}{p-1}})^{p-1}\\
&\leq \min(k,\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Bwdx)((\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx)^{p-1}+k^{-1})\\
&\leq (\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qwdx)(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx)^{p-1}+k^{1-1}\\
&\leq  (\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qwdx)(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}dx)^{p-1}+1\\
&\leq 2[w]_{A_p}
\end{align*}
where in the last inequality I used the fact that $A_p$ constants are bounded below by 1. This indeed shows that $\min(w,k)\in A_p$. However, the coefficient I get is not the same as the one suggested in the problem. I am wondering wether this is a typo or there exists another way of manipulating these inequalities. (Also in the case that $2<p<\infty$, the $c_p$ I obtained is $2^{p}$ instead of $2^{p-1}$.)

Would you describe what $A_p$ denotes? Maybe it’s a very well-recognized notation and I’m one of the few who hasn’t run into it before. I guess for that matter I don’t know what $[ ,\cdot, ]_{A_p}$ is supposed to mean either.

A weight $w$ is a nonnegative locally integrable function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. A weight is in $A_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ if $\sup_{Q \text{cubes in }\mathbb{R}^n}(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qwdx)(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Qw^{-\frac{1}{p-1}})dx)^{p-1}<\infty$. This quantity is also the $A_p$ constant denoted by $[w]_{A_p}$.
